# SQL Server : cannot connect to a named instance

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error when trying to log in to a named SQL Server 2016 instance:

> 2017-03-31 09:25:19.12 Logon
>   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
>   2017-03-31 09:25:19.12 Logon
>   Login failed for user 'domain\user'.  Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: some-ip-address

SQL Server 2016 is a named instance on this box as it also has SQL Server 2012 instance and was installed using virtual accounts as outlined here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions

This named instance is running under port 1500.

Any ideas on how to connect to this server using SQL Server Management Studio ?

Comment: The error implies everything is installed and running properly, it's just that windows account doesn't have access to log into the SQL Server. In the first instance, confirm that it's installed and running by checking services. Referring to your link, under _Database Engine Provisioning_, how did you configure security? Which windows account did you name as a member of sysadmin? and did you enable the `sa` account

Answer (score 2):

A virtual account is used to run the SQL Server Service but you wouldn't be able to login using that account as there is no way to know the password.  In addition it's a local account only so domain\user is not going to work.

You should have had to grant SOME user access to the server, I think by default it grants the user who is installing the SQL Server so if you know that account you could try logging in with that.  Also if you know the sa password that should work too.

Past that you are probably looking at putting the server in single user mode and adding a login just to get in.  See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlman/2011/06/14/tips-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what/)